# Automatic Way To Rotate An HTML Table And Its Columns From Horizontal To Vertical

Tags: html, css, html-table

I already have a table in HTML, it can be seen below:

```
<table border ="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Festival Name:</td>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td>List of Trips to </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>      
            <td>Reading</td>
            <td>2013-04-03</td>
            <td>2013-04-07</td>
            <td>
                <a href="ControllerServlet?festivalProfileLink=2">View Profile and trips</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

However the problem with it is that it doesn't fit on my HTML website correctly due to me having put a banner down the left and right hand sides. Is there any way of being able to automatically rotate the table vertically so that all the data will fit on the page?

Answer (score 1):

I put together two options in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/YvRG7/2/)

Option 1

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Festival Name:</td>
            <td>Reading</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td>2013-04-03</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td>2013-04-07</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>List of Trips to</td>
            <td><a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ControllerServlet?festivalProfileLink=2">View Profile and trips</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

option2

css:

```
   .box {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    top:250px;
    transform-origin:left;
    transform:rotate(90deg); /* -webkit-, -moz-, etc. omitted for brevity */
}
```

html:

```
<div class="box">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Festival Name:</td>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td>List of Trips to</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Reading</td>
            <td>2013-04-03</td>
            <td>2013-04-07</td>
            <td> <a href="ControllerServlet?festivalProfileLink=2">View Profile and trips</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I wasn't to sure if you really wanted to rotate it.

Comment: I can't really get option 2 to affect the table. Is there something that's missing? I also know I can just alter the table but that's not automatic as the table is arranged how I said automatically due to it being posted from a Java Servlet.

Comment: @edwoollard you will likely need to play with the positioning, tables seem to rotate a bit strangely.

Comment: It just displays very similarly to what I already have in my example for the second option? The first option is how I would like it to work but I need something that forces the table to change to that format automatically as once the servlet posts the data, I cannot really mess with the table and change the columns and rows.

Comment: Also, out of interest...what does the <tbody> tag do? I can't seem to notice a difference?

Comment: @edwoollard The <tbody> tag is used to group the body content in an HTML table. Its not really necessary unless accompanied by <thead> and <tfoot>. My CMS adds it when I play with tables.

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/YvRG7/3/ with vendor prefixes. Note, Older versions of IE don't support transfom.

Comment: Yeah that shows up with the rotation now thanks. That would be feasible but can't really have the text sideways too. The first option is how I want it to display, so I guess I'll have to play around and hopefully I can alter what the servlet sends back into a table. Thanks for all your effort though!